# Repeated vowels and consonants in words in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
a_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5],'text':['This was fuuuuun','aaaawesome','Hiiigh altitude','Oops','See you']})

a_df
    id  text
0   1   This was fuuuuun
1   2   aaaawesome
2   3   Hiiigh altitude
3   4   Oops
4   5   See you
```

Some words are misspelled. One rule to apply is to that, if I see three or more vowels or consonants, then I could be somehow sure that there is a misspelled word, so I replace that repetition with ''.

So I have tried this:

```
a_df['corrected_text'] = a_df['text'].str.replace(r'([a-zA-Z])\\3+','')
```

But there is no change. My logic was to try to capture letters that were repeated, but I must be doing something wrong. Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `a_df['text'].str.replace(r'([a-zA-Z])\1{2,}',r'\1')`

Comment: Hello @WiktorStribiżew, thank you very much, I tested it and works fine. Please, just a question for me to learn, why the usage of `\1{2,}`?

Comment: I hope I explained it well in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
a_df['text'] = a_df['text'].str.replace(r'([a-zA-Z])\1{2,}', r'\1', regex=True)
```

Details:

- `([a-zA-Z])` - capturing group with ID 1
- `\1{2,}` - two or more occurrences (so, three or more letters together with the previous pattern) of Group 1 value (`\1` is a replacement backreference to Group 1 value, make sure to use it in a raww string literal, else you would have to double backslashes).

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew, you know besides the great answer, the explanation of groups and the back reference replacement helps me more to learn and investigate on the regex usage. I appreciate your time and kind explanation. Have a great, great day!

Comment: Just as an added bonus, I investigated more on the `{x,}` and it means "at least x number of occurrences". I'm quite happy to learn from the great people of SO. This is the link where I learned that: http://vertstudios.com/blog/back-references-quantifiers-and-anchors-in-regex/

Answer (score 1):

Lets try replace every three consecutive vowels with '' as follows

```
a_df['text'].str.replace('([aeiou]{3})','', regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @wwnde. Can I do the same to consonants and vowels at the same time?

Comment: I would go @wiktor's approach if you need a mix